# Correct cmake setup to include headers

Tags: cmake

I have a project structured like this:

```
─root
  ├──src
  │   ├──main.cpp
  │   └──CMakeLists.txt[2]
  ├──build
  ├──out
  ├──inc
  ├──dep
  │   ├──log
  │   │   ├──include
  │   │   │     └──log.h
  │   │   ├──src
  │   │   │   └──log.cpp
  │   │   └──CMakeLists.txt[4]
  │   └──CMakeLists.txt[3]
  └──CMakeLists.txt[1]
```

Under `dep` I have a logging library, which is an external git repository with his own `CMakeLists.txt` file.

The main `CMakeLists.txt` (marked as [1]) is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
set(APP_ROOT ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
add_subdirectory(dep)
add_subdirectory(src)
```

The `CMakeLists.txt` (marked as [2]) for the current project code is:

```
add_executable(app main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(app log)
include_directories("${APP_ROOT}/inc")
```

The `CMakeLists.txt` (marked as [3]) for the dependencies is:

```
add_subdirectory(log)
```

What I'm trying to do is to have the contents of the `dep/log/include` folder copied inside a new folder called `inc/log`, so that in `main.cpp` I can write something like `#include <log/log.h>`, but I don't understand how. I would like to avoid editing the `CMakeLists.txt` of the logger project.

Comment: Sorry, can't contribute to answer, but can't help pressing +1 for  ASCII graphics.

Comment: Your solution looks good to me - I'd add it as an answer.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just add log's include directory to the compiler include path?

Comment: @szx yes, but I want to have separate libraries headers in separate subfolders to avoid name clashing.

Comment: @Fraser Thank you, I just started using cmake so I wasn't really sure if I was using correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution: in `/dep/CMakeLists.txt` I added

```
file(MAKE_DIRECTORY "${APP_ROOT}/inc/log")
file(COPY "log/include/" DESTINATION "${APP_ROOT}/inc/log")
```